# Ограничения generic метода

Tags: c#, generics

Каким образом можно задать ограничения *generic* методу?

```
class Convert
{
    public static T convertFrom <T>(string value)
    {
        return new T(); //Не работает, нужно как-то задать ограничения new(), но как?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static T convertFrom <T>(string value) where T : new()
{
    return new T(); 
}
```

Подробнее: [new Constraint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) ([на русском](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint))